# How to animate rotation of projection vectors on XY,YZ and XZ plane

Tags: animation, workflow, animation-nodes

I want to make an animation of a main vector (which is an arrow) rotating in all xyz directions about the global origin. In addition, three different arrows representing the projections of the main vector on the XY, YZ and XZ plane, respectively rotate with the main vector on their respective planes.

How can I do this using animation nodes?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean, it should look like this:

https://youtu.be/TSl5OJdv6Lc (please be a little bit patient because my internet connection is not that blazing fast)

you can do it like this:

[image]

where "cube" is the main vector, and red, green and blue are the projected vectors.

Comment: I am expecting all the three projected vectors should rotate simultaneously with the main vector, while remain confined within their respective planes. The rotation of all the four vectors ( one main and three projected vectors) will be in such a harmony that every time the tip of the arrow head of any projected vector becomes co-linear with that of the main one. Therefore, when the main vector becomes parallel to one of the global axis the length of the projected vector on the plane perpendicular to the that axis vanishes.

Comment: i showed you how to animate the angles in animation nodes. I hope you can adapt the length of the vectors yourself. And by the way - this is a "we help you with your project what you tried so far" not a "we make everything from nothing for you"- platform

Comment: Actually this was my first test project. I have started to learn the Blender just a couple of days earlier. I was trying with rotation to direction and direction to rotation nodes to achieve this. I couldn’t manage the animation having rotation and scaling in length simultaneously. But what you suggest that is a great learning for me but not the exact thing what I was searching for. I can understand it’s my mistake that I couldn’t convey my thinking properly. I am sorry for that and thank you for what you have taught me today. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem. We all started one day and learnt more and more. Here on this site you can kind of show your „thank you“ by tapping on „right answer“ or/and tapping that up arrow beneath the answer.